# .htaccess redirecting to index page, when adding new pages to site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

1st: I have http://pastebin.com/L7FVXjDU .htaccess file, now I want to add a new file /admin/index.php added this line to .htaccess: `RewriteRule ^admin/([0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php [L,QSA]` but this redirect to home page.

2nd: in case of file not found 404 error, I want to redirect to notfound.html added this line: `ErrorDocument 404 contents/notfound.html`

but no success!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php  index.htm index.cgi    
ErrorDocument 404 contents/notfound.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#index.php to host
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#admin home
RewriteRule ^admin/([0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php [L,QSA]

#pagination rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?$ index.php?page=$2&c_id=$3 [L,QSA]

#business review rewriting
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ contents/details.php?b_id=$4&status=$5 [L,QSA]

#business rewriting
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ contents/details.php?b_id=$4 [L,QSA]

#claim page rewriting
RewriteRule ^claim/([0-9]+)/?$ contents/claim.php?b_id=$1 [L,QSA]

#report page rewriting
RewriteRule ^report/([0-9]+)/?$ contents/report.php?b_id=$1 [L,QSA]

#rewrite host to index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*?)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]

#main pages rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f    
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ contents/$1.php [L]

#category rewriting
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?$ [L]
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # ******************* admin *************************
```

Comment: the same result. 1 strange thing more, the Macromedia Dreamweaver show the file activity again and again, even I closed the file there. here is the log:  Started: 5/10/2014 8:39 PM

.htaccess - Put operation successful

File activity complete.
Files updated: 1

Finished: 5/10/2014 8:39 PM

Comment: Unless you provide concrete information I can't investigate. What URL do you see in the browser? What was error? Where is this .htaccess located etc?

Comment: here are the info you need. (1) I am trying www.mydomain.com/admin/index.php and same is displayed in the browser. (2) there is no error. (3) the .htaccess is located in root folder. hope now you can investigate.

Comment: Try it now. `www.mydomain.com/admin/index.php` should load normally if `/admin/index.php` is a valid file.

Comment: same result: please check www.star-business-directory.com/admin/index.php

Comment: `www.star-business-directory.com/admin/index.php` behaves fine. It removed `index.php` due to first 301 rule and rest worked fine. What problem do you see with `www.star-business-directory.com/admin/index.php`?

Comment: may be I couldn't explain the problem properly. /admin/index.php redirect me to home page. As I am new to this .htaccess, one of my friend told my last night that any index.php is redirecting to home page. now I have solved the problem by renaming the /admin/index.php to /admin/abc_index.php so its fine working. can you explain the "due to first 301 rule and rest worked fine" in your last comment?

Comment: here is the new version of .htaccess http://pastebin.com/pbU9h1ub. Now my 2nd problem ErrorDocument 404 /contents/notfound.html that is not working.

Comment: The first rule with the comment `index.php to host` is removing `/index.php` from any where in the URL and redirecting `/anything/here/index.php` to `/anything/here/`. Hope it is more clear to you now.